# How to create tables from entity with respect to their datasource in JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, multiple-databases

Suppose I have two datasources primarydb,secondarydb also having two entities
entity1 , entity2. So When I add **spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update** .
Here entity1 should get created in primarydb and entity2 should created in secondarydb.
but this is not happening it's creating in primarydb only.

and second thing if I want to add onetomany on entity1 with entity2 it's also not works

```
@ManyToOne
private Entity2 entity2;
```

application.properties

```
#actuator
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always

#server.servlet.context-path=/ajax

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://@datasource.server@:3306/primarydb?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=@datasource.username@
spring.datasource.password=@datasource.password@
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=30
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=30000
spring.datasource.tomcat.maxActive=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.maxIdle=30
spring.datasource.tomcat.minIdle=30
spring.datasource.tomcat.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=300000
server.session.tracking-modes=cookie
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true


#another db
datasource.secondary.hikari.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://@datasource.server@/secondarydb:3306?useSSL=false
datasource.secondary.hikari.username=@datasource.username@
datasource.secondary.hikari.password=@datasource.password@
datasource.secondary.hikari.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

datasource.secondary.hikari.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
datasource.secondary.hikari.minimum-idle=30
datasource.secondary.hikari.maximum-idle=30
datasource.secondary.hikari.idle-timeout=300000
datasource.secondary.hikari.max-lifetime=300000
datasource.secondary.hikari.pool-name=SecondaryPool
datasource.secondary.hikari.connection-timeout=30000
datasource.secondary.hikari.maximum-pool-size=70
```

configuration file

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.secondary.hikari")
    public HikariConfig hikariConfigForSecondaryDatasource() {
        return new HikariConfig();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondaryDataSource")
    public DataSource dataSourceForSecondaryDatasource() {
        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfigForSecondaryDatasource());
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSourceForPrimaryDatasource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please add all relevant configuration and sources?

Comment: @tmarwen updated please check.